# REST API gives a response code 500 "internal server error"

Tags: android, server, backend, internal-server-error, http-status-code-500

I am sending media file to my backend server through my app and image and video files are sent as a media file using same api endpoint. The images are sent without any errors. Videos were also sent without any errors but now the api response for video files is 500 internal server error. Also when I test the api with a video file in postman then the response is fine. I am unable to find what's wrong.

Comment: Can you run debug on your server? Do you have any logs?

Comment: Your backend server is failing, so you must look into the logs and figure out what's happening. For sure something has changed and now it's throwing exceptions.